# How to use ng-class with a boolean from a service in angular.js ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I want to set a class based on the boolean that I set in a service. This is a **simplified version** from my code (for the sake of readability). The boolean is normally set by a lot of other functions in this service.

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-class="{ 'green' : MainController.CustomService.isGreen }">
    </div>
</div>
```

Service :

```
App.service("CustomService", function() {
    this.isGreen = true;
})
```

Controller :

```
App.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'CustomService',  function($scope, CustomService) {

}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
App.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'CustomService',  function($scope, CustomService) {
    $scope.isGreen = CustomService.isGreen;
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'green' : isGreen }">
```

View does not have direct access to service. View has access to `$scope` object, So if you need something in view, you shall write in `$scope` first.

If you want to track color:

```
App.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'CustomService',  function($scope, CustomService) {
    $scope.isGreen = function () {
        return CustomService.isGreen;
    };
}]);
```

And:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'green' : isGreen() }">
```

Comment: But this doesn't work when the variable in my service changes.

Answer (score 1):

Only properties of `$scope` are accessible to the view. So when you say `MainController.CustomService.isGreen` in the view, Angular tries to access `$scope.MainController.CustomService.isGreen`, which does not exist. You should publish the service to the scope in your controller.

```
App.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'CustomService',  function($scope, CustomService) {
    $scope.CustomService = CustomService;
}]);
```

Then you can access your service from the view like this:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'green' : CustomService.isGreen }">
</div>
```

Another slightly different, more popular approach is to instruct the controller to publish itself in the scope. You do this by tweaking the `ng-controller` value to `MainController as $ctrl` (the name could be anything but Angular 1.5 standardized $ctrl). Then `$ctrl` becomes available in your view:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'green' : $ctrl.CustomService.isGreen }">
</div>
```

In the controller function, `$ctrl` corresponds to `this`, so to publish the service, you would do:

```
App.controller('MainController', ['CustomService',  function(CustomService) {
        this.CustomService = CustomService;
}]);
```

Notice you don't need to inject `$scope` as a parameter now.